# Most concise way to assign a value from a variable only if it exists in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

Anyone knows of a more concise/elegant way of achieving the following?

`A = B if B?`

Thanks.

### EDIT:

I'm looking for a solution that references A and B once only. And would compile to
`if (typeof B !== "undefined" && B !== null) { A = B; }`
or something else similar.

To have this short helps have the following a bit more readable:
`someObject[someAttribute] = (someOtherObject[someOtherAttribute] if someOtherObject[someOtherAttribute]?)`
That is the motivation for my question.

Comment: Looks already extremely elegant to me? What do you expect more?

Comment: Something with A and B referenced only once. Sorry, my original question lacked specificity indeed.

Comment: *Best:*
Coffeescript:
 `a = b ? a`
 
Javascipt: 
 `var a;
 a = typeof b !== "undefined" && b !== null ? b : a;`

*Good* 
Coffeescript:
 `A = B if B?`
Javascript:
 `var A;
 if (typeof B !== "undefined" && B !== null) {
   A = B;
 }` 
 
I would pick "mu is too short" answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could say:

```
a = b ? a
```

For example, this:

```
a = 11
a = b ? a
console.log(a)
b = 23
a = b ? a
console.log(a)​
```

will give you `11` and `23` in the console (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ngtEE/)

Comment: Ah. Thanks. That is indeed way shorter. However, I'm looking for a solution referencing A and B once only. Sorry, my original question lacked specificity in that regards. Editing this in.

Comment: Btw, I just noticed your username. Serendipity?

Comment: @user473911: Is `someArray` an array or an object?

Comment: @muistooshort: thanks catching the typo. It's an object that I had in mind...even though, ultimately, arrays are objects in javascript.

Comment: @LarryBattle, it is indeed the best answer so far.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like:

```
A=_ if (_=B)?
```

expanded:

```
if ((_ = B) != null) {
  A = _;
}
```

This will overwrite A with what ever is in B, but only if it is not null, referencing both only once.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Coffee Script but you can use the OR operator for this in regular javascript like so:

`a = b || a`